# How to align text with 2 lines with a text of one line in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So, I want the row with a string of 2 lines ("Some long string with 2 lines heres") to be properly aligned with the string of 1 line: ("Name:"), but I want to do this WITHOUT checking the string length.

This is my code for the row:

```dart
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(
      title,
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6.copyWith(height: 1.24),
    ),
    Spacer(),
    Container(
      width: 242.0,
      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
      child: Text(
        text,
        textAlign: TextAlign.end,
        maxLines: 2,
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.apply(
              color: kGrey,
            ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

As for the result I want, here's an image example:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `crossAxisAlignment` `Row` parameter to align the text to start  `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start`

Solution-

```
       Row(
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                title,
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .headline6
                    .copyWith(height: 1.24),
              ),
              Spacer(),
              Container(
                width: 242.0,
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                child: Text(
                  text,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                  maxLines: 2,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.apply(
                   color: kGrey,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Hope this will help you If you have any doubts ask in comment.

Comment: Wow, it was that simple. Thanks!